# QGIS Map Atlas sub-region label names highlight

Tags: qgis, labeling, atlas

In QGIS Atlas, I can use `$id = @atlas_featureid` and `$id <> @atlas_featureid` to highlight the label names of my main region  (Fig.1: more clear name in the AOI than the outside ones). How can we do similar highlight to the label names other layers or sub-regions, have to link with Atlas setting? E.g. in Fig.2, I want the label names (in English) outside the AOI are transparent than the inside ones.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagining your subregion table has a column with the same region code mentioned in it attributes as in one column of the subregion layer, you can add a label rule within "Rule-based Labeling" with the following condition

```
attribute(@atlas_feature, 'COL_NAME_REGION_CODE_FROM_COVERAGE') = "COL_NAME_REGION_CODE_IN_YOUR_LAYER"
```

where `'COL_NAME_REGION_CODE_FROM_COVERAGE'` is the column name in your coverage layer feature and code region column in your current subregion layer is `"COL_NAME_REGION_CODE_IN_YOUR_LAYER"`

You could use also compare geometry from atlas selected feature with the geometry of your subregion layer using something like:

```
within(point_on_surface($geometry), @atlas_geometry)
```

It would be quite inefficient to check spatial relationships on the fly each time. It can be a possible solution if no matching column code between your tables, but I prefer adding a column in the subregion layer and fill it once using the same spatial relationship logic instead of calculating it on the fly each time.

Comment: Thank you Thomas for your quick help. In my Region and Subregion layers have one same column named ADM1_PCODE with the same code, so if I'm not wrong, the statement could be: attribute( @atlas_feature , 'ADM1_PCODE') = "ADM1_PCODE". But it doesn't show any names of Subregion yet.

Comment: within(point_on_surface($geometry), @atlas_geometry) doesn't show the label names on the map also.

Comment: Did you activate the atlas? Both works on my own sample.

Comment: Where did you set the expression? In your subregion layer labels panel properties?

Comment: It works now. Sorry, it's my mistake to not select the field name in Value field. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad you solve your issue

Comment: However, I'm still struggling with the transparent label names outside the highlighted map.